# Why is this HTML5 document invalid?

Tags: html

I'm getting pretty confused about an error message I'm getting when I try to validate any simple HTML document without a meta encoding like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>Test</body>
</html>
```

[The W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org) reluctantly accepts the document as valid with just a few warnings when it is pasted into the direct input form, but when the document is uploaded or loaded by URI, validation fails with this error message

> The character encoding was not declared. Proceeding using
> windows-1252.

There are two things I don't understand about this error:

- Why is a missing character encoding considered an error, when fallback rules exist?
- Why is the validator assuming [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) instead of UTF-8, like any browser would?

What is the explanation for these two points?

Comment: What makes you think a browser assumes UTF-8 when no encoding is specified? What “fallback rules” are you referring to?

Comment: Does windows-1252 encoding work though?

Comment: Interesting... your html example shown validates as html5/utf8 when I paste it into the validate by direct input window

Comment: Just to note that the validator says that character encoding is "often recommended" and that the validator defaults to UTF-8 for direct input. "If you notice a discrepancy in detected character encoding between the “Direct Input” mode and other validator modes, this is likely to be the reason. It is neither a bug in the validator, nor in your document."

Comment: Andrew, I know modern browsers assume UTF-8 when an encoding is missing, and this is easy to see if you put some Unicode characters in the HTML body. As for the fallback rules, if none exist, then why am I getting windows-1252 at all?

Comment: Worth reading: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) (alternate title: There ain't no such thing as plain text)

Comment: @KathBrown I find it interesting that you *know* that since it’s not true. Neither the latest version of Chrome (28) nor Firefox (22) assume UTF-8 (they both use ISO-8859-1 by default). Firefox even gives a warning in the console about non-ASCII characters. There are no fallback rules other than the fallback when no encoding specified. Your assumptions are all wrong.

Comment: It is not in this question's sample HTML content, but `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` may not be sufficient. There is the *exact*  same symptom if there is an HTML comment and/or white space that is ***longer than about 1024 bytes*** before the `meta` tag. From [this](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/what-goes-wrong/309037): *"The <meta> element declaring the encoding must be inside the <head> element and within the first 1024 bytes of the HTML as some browsers only look at those bytes before choosing an encoding."* The validator may use a similar rule.

Comment: Or in other words, an HTML comment ***in the beginning*** that is ***too long*** will result in the same symptom.

Answer (score 15):

Well, it depends on what you are using.

- if you are using the [File Upload](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload) option, it depends on which
  encoding the HTML file was saved with.
- if you are using the [Direct    Input](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) option, it depends on the
  navigator.

If you don't want the validator to guess, and use [UTF-8](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3629.txt), you can add the following line

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

inside the the [head element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/head.html).

Comment: Direct Input mode does not depend on the navigator. From the validating page: "Unlike the “by URI” and “by File Upload” modes, the “Direct Input” mode of the validator provides validated content in the form of characters pasted or typed in the validator's form field. This will automatically make the data UTF-8, and therefore the validator does not need to determine the character encoding of your document, and will ignore any charset information specified."

Answer (score 6):

It is the "Direct Input" mode of the validator that defaults to UTF-8. User-agents (browsers) will default to other encodings based on a number of things:

[From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML):

> If a user agent reads a document with no character encoding
> information, it can fall back to using some other information. For
> example, it can rely on the user's settings, either browser-wide or
> specific for a given document, or it can pick a default encoding based
> on the user's language. For Western European languages, it is typical
> and fairly safe to assume Windows-1252, which is similar to ISO-8859-1
> but has printable characters in place of some control codes.

Answer (score 3):

The W3C validator said:

> The validator checked your document with an experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker. This feature has been made available for your convenience, but be aware that it may be unreliable, or not perfectly up to date with the latest development of some cutting-edge technologies.

So take some results with a pinch of salt.

Also, there isn't any useful 'fallback'. The validator just needs to pick something/anything so it can try to validate for you.

W3C can't determine/decide what encoding you want/need to use. You must declare it yourself based on what characters you need to serve on your web page(s), and then ask W3C to validate your document based on that.

Comment: The "Direct Input" mode that the OP is referring to will "automatically make the data UTF-8" and "ignore any charset information". See my comment to Campari.

Comment: Fair point. Although it doesn't strictly "ignore any charset information" as it changes the meta charset provided if it's not utf-8 (and places the charset provided by the user in HTML comment code)

Answer (score 2):

When you use Validate by URI, the server is supposed to announce the character encoding in HTTP headers, more exactly in the *charset* parameter of the *Content-Type* header value. In this case, this apparently does not happen. You can check the situation, e.g., using [Rex Swain's HTTP Viewer](http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html).

According to clause [4.2.5.5 Specifying the document's character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset) in HTML5 CR, “If an HTML document does not start with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and its encoding is not explicitly given by *Content-Type* metadata, and the document is not an iframe srcdoc document, then the character encoding used must be an ASCII-compatible character encoding, and the encoding must be specified using a meta element with a *charset* attribute or a meta element with an *http-equiv* attribute in the Encoding declaration state.” This is a bit complicated, but the bottom line is: there are several ways to declare the encoding, but if none of them is used, the document is non-conforming.

*Why* it specifies so is somewhat speculative, but the general idea is that such rules promote reliability and robustness. When the rule is not obeyed, different browsers may use different defaults or guesswork.

The validator assumes Windows-1252, because that’s what HTML5 rules lead to. The processing rules are in [8.2.2.1 Determining the character encoding](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding). They are fairly complicated, but they largely reflect the way modern browsers do (and aims at making it a standard). The rules there are meant to deal with non-conforming documents, too, but this does not make those documents conforming; error processing rules are not really “fallbacks” and should not be relied on, especially since old browsers do not always play by the rules.

The error rules get somewhat loose when it comes to a situation where everything else fails and an “implementation-defined or user-specified default character encoding” is to be used. There are just “suggestions” on what browsers might do (again, reflecting what modern browsers generally do), and this may involve using the “user’s locale”, an obscure concept. The validator uses Windows-1252 then, perhaps because that’s the default for English and the validator “speaks” English, or maybe just because it’s the guess that is expected to be correct more often than any other single alternative.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` may not be sufficient. A ***1024 bytes rule*** has to be obeyed as well. For example, an HTML comment in beginning that is too long may also cause this problem. From [this](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/what-goes-wrong/309037): *"The <meta> element declaring the encoding must be inside the <head> element and within the first 1024 bytes of the HTML as some browsers only look at those bytes before choosing an encoding."* The validator may use a similar rule. I couldn't get it to match exactly, but it was within about 10%.

Comment: cont' - That is, I can confirm empirically that there is definitely a limit.